# Cannot press the advanced button in wpf toolkit color picker

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, color-picker

I am using the [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) to add a color picker to my application. I am having an issue that I can see the simple mode of the color picker in the runtime without issue, but when I click on the Advanced button, I always get an exception:

Could not load file or assembly 'WPFToolkit, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"WPFToolkit, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

I've checked and make sure the assembly is in the right folder. How can I see the first part but cannot see the second part?

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says you are missing the WPF Toolkit, which is a different .dll than the Extended WPF Toolkit.

The downloads page for the Extended Toolkit mentions you need to have the WPF Toolkit installed.

> Requires .NET Framework 4.0 or 4.5. A build for .NET 3.5 is available
>   but also requires the WPFToolkit to be installed.

The WPF Toolkit can be found here: http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that. It works now with the WPFToolKit dll added to the project.